# Unable to fix/remove old version of unit from snap

Tags: boot, 20.04, xubuntu, snap

So, looking around the internet, I've found a bunch of issues and solutions. The main solution that I keep finding is `sudo snap remove {package}`, unfortunately, the package doesn't show (at least the version) in `snap list`.

```
$ snap list
Name                    Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher     Notes
chromium                87.0.4280.88                1424   latest/stable    canonical✓    -
core                    16-2.48.2                   10583  latest/stable    canonical✓    core
core18                  20201210                    1944   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
discord                 0.0.13                      120    latest/stable    snapcrafters  -
foobar2000              1.6.2                       315    latest/stable    mmtrt         -
gnome-3-26-1604         3.26.0.20200529             100    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-28-1804         3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804         0+git.3556cb3               60     latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-system-monitor    3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7       148    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gtk2-common-themes      0.1                         13     latest/stable    canonical✓    -
p7zip-desktop           16.02.2                     220    latest/stable    ernytech      -
remmina                 v1.4.10+git5.717708b1       4587   latest/stable    remmina✓      -
rocketchat-desktop      3.0.1                       196    latest/stable    rocketchat✓   -
snap-store              3.38.0-59-g494f078          518    latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
vlc                     3.0.11                      1700   latest/stable    videolan✓     -
wine-platform-3-stable  3.0.4                       11     latest/stable    mmtrt         -
wine-platform-5-stable  5.0.3                       16     latest/stable    mmtrt         -
wine-platform-runtime   v1.0                        200    latest/stable    mmtrt         -
```

When I boot my system, it says something like `Failed to mount unit: gtk2-common-themes version 9`. So, to show that I'm not crazy:

```
$ systemctl --all --failed
  UNIT                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                  
● snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-9.mount loaded failed failed Mount unit for gtk2-common-themes, revision 9

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

As you can see above, I have a working version of 13, not 9. Somehow both are "installed" or at least version 9 is hanging around and 13 is installed.

What I've done:

- Removed both gtk and gtk2 and reinstalled them.

What I'm asking for:

- A way to stop the system from trying to boot version 9
- Or repair snap from causing this issue

Thanks

- Update Answer *

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/1305880/1168565 https://askubuntu.com/users/261753/kyle

I was able to do the following:

```
$ snap list --all gtk2-common-themes
Name                Version  Rev  Tracking       Publisher   Notes
gtk2-common-themes           9    latest/stable  canonical✓  disabled,broken
gtk2-common-themes  0.1      13   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
$ sudo snap remove --revision=9 gtk2-common-themes
gtk2-common-themes (revision 9) removed
```

Comment: What does "*Removed both gtk and gtk2 and reinstalled them*" mean? Edit your question to show us the actual input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes without saying that you shouldn't be seeing that error, and I'm not sure why it's happening. It might be worth opening a thread on https://forum.snapcraft.io/ to let the developers know that something weird is going on and try to get to the bottom of it.

That said, maybe we can stop the error. Snaps automatically update, and part of the way they make that process robust is by keeping multiple snap revisions around in case it needs to revert. These revisions are still mounted, etc., which is I think related to the error you're seeing.

You can see all revisions of the snap on your system, including inactive ones, by using the `--all` option, e.g.:

```
$ snap list --all gtk2-common-themes
```

Assuming you have revision 9 installed and you only care about the current one (13, it seems), you can try simply removing 9:

```
$ sudo snap remove --revision=9 gtk2-common-themes
```

Again, even if that works, this is only working around the error, it doesn't explain why it's happening in the first place. That will require some debugging, and thus a forum post like I suggested.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I think you might have missed the `2` in `gtk2-common-themes`, but it's worth while as an answer. I didn't know you could see the individual revisions and delete them separately.

Comment: Whoops, you're right I missed that. Fixed!